# Is there a 'not found' exception for jquery selector?

Tags: jquery

I just spent 'hours' with the following scenario: (all back to the basics)

```
 $('#typo').bind('click' etc ...
```

I had a typo in the selector, but jQuery  resolves

```
$('#funny something out there').bind(...
```

without any warning.

Is it possible to tell jQuery to raise an error when your selector gets nothing?

Something like this:

```
 $('#typo', alert('Stupid, nothing here! like '+ '#typo))
```

**edit**

I spoke against me:

```
$('#typo', alert('Stupid, nothing here! like '+ '#typo))
```

is not a solutiuon. I have to know where the error is to extend  the selector

Comment: jquery doesn't know if that's a wrong selector. You can certainly check for its length `$selector.length` & then bind the event.

Comment: You can check `$('#typo').length`, but that's something I would do after debugging led me to wonder if my selector was wrong.

Comment: @JasonP you sayd it: _after debugging_

Comment: @halfbit So in that case, I would add `console.log($('#typo'))` above the line that adds the handler and see what the console says.

Comment: @JasonP - yes. you're right.

Comment: @all: I found the typo with these tricks/ideas, I was asking if there is a jQuery (built in) logic

Comment: no there isn't...jQuery will fail silently if elements in selector not found

Comment: @charlietfl: ok, it is not, i suggest a 'strict' logic for jQuery

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use following snippet:

**UPDATED** to take care of context

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J27AZ/)

```
jQuery.debug = true;
$ = function (selector, context) {
    if (jQuery.debug && typeof selector === "string" && !jQuery(selector, context).length) 
        throw new Error("No element found!");
    return jQuery.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: I suggest using this snippet, but instead of throwing an error, just logging a warning if the console exists. You can then include this as a debugging tool and just exclude it from production code.

Comment: @KevinB ya, correct. I was guessing adding just a debug boolean property could be enough. BTW, still need to check for context too, but that gives the idea

Comment: Changed it from "throw new Error(" to "console.error(" and I'm a VERY happy camper, now.  This will be an enormouse time saver!! THANKS

Answer (score 2):

```
var element = $('#typo');
if (element.length > 0) {
    // element exists
}
```

Short of that, you would have to modify the jQuery source code to get that behavior.

Comment: hm, so this would me a sugestion for a next jQuery version :=> 'Short of that, you would have to modify the jQuery source code to get that behavior.'

Comment: @halfbit The fact that jQuery *doesn't* throw an exception is widely considered a huge benefit.

Comment: $tell_me_my_bad_things=true, could solve that, isn't it?

Comment: Modifying jquery is not a good idea for maintainability. Suggest you check the length if an empty selector will cause a problem. In general there are good reasons why you may want a selector to return zero length. e.g. Binding to an element which will be added in the future

Answer (score 0):

The jquery selector returns an array of DOM Elements so if you check the length of it, if it is greater than 0 it found something, if it is equal to 0 it didn't

```
  if($("selector").length > 0) found;
```

Comment: this code I can use as soon as i understood, and found  my 'typo'

Answer (score 0):

You can use the length of the returned DOM elements as a falsy and throw a new `error` like so:

```
var el = '#el';

if ($(el).length){
    // Do Stuff
} else {
    throw new Error("Element "+el+" Doesn't Exist");
}
```

**OR**

```
// Ignores Empty Selector
if ($('#el').length){
    // Do Stuff
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: this code I can use as soon as i understood, and found  my 'typo'