# Throw error if jQuery selector does not match

Tags: jquery

When a selector does not match, how can jQuery be changed such that an error is thrown?

For example, assume that this selector does not match:

```
var missing = $("#idNotInHtmlDoc").length == 0;  //<-- selector does not match
```

Is it possible to override the behaviour of jQuery to throw an error on the line above?

Comment: Not built in, but try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20621666/is-there-a-not-found-exception-for-jquery-selector

Answer (score 0):

something like this may be helpful:

```
 $.fn.element_exists = function() {
      if (this.length === 0) throw "Empty result."
      return this;
    }
```

usage:

```
var missing = $("#idNotInHtmlDoc").element_exists();
```